# How to run an X11 application in weston via xwayland

Tags: x11, nvidia, xfce, wayland

I was told that most X11 applications should as well run on wayland, when using xwayland.

I am not sure if I fail to call weston in a proper way, or if the application does something special, which is not supported by xwayland. So here what I do:

1. Login (xfce session), open some terminal
2. `weston --backend=x11-backend.so --xwayland`
3. open a terminal in the weston session
4. `xfce4-screenshooter`
5. Take some screenshot (no mater if whole screen or window)--> crash

As well `parole`(xfce4 media player) crashes for me on startup in weston.

So is it the fault of screenshooter/parole, by doing some weird X11 stuff, or should I just launch weston in a different way ?

Comment: Have you tried another Wayland compositor?

Comment: Nope, I used weston, since that is the reference implementation. I only want to test.

Comment: You can answer the second paragraph yourself if you try another compositor

Comment: A friend as well took a try: Works fine for him with weston and the commands above. I suppose the culpit is, that I used a nvidia driver instead of nouveau. Will take another try with nouveau when I have time.

Comment: Oh, nvidia's proprietary blob doesn't work with Wayland. That's a known problem.

Comment: yea .. the tricky part is, that the nvidia blob even works in some cases for wayland. I forgot about that aspect, since e.g. thunar just runs fine with that driver on weston without xwayland.